# State Space model code from Time Series analysis Springer book, and code error from optimization

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I'm trying to apply State Space model code from the book, Time Series analysis and its applications from Springer book, to my data.

The code is as below:

```
num = length(jj)
A = cbind(1,1,0,0) 
# Function to Calculate Likelihood 
Linn =function(para){ 
  Phi = diag(0,4)
  Phi[1,1] = para[1] 
  Phi[2,]=c(0,-1,-1,-1)
  Phi[3,]=c(0,1,0,0)
  Phi[4,]=c(0,0,1,0) 
  cQ1 = para[2]; cQ2 = para[3] # sqrt q11 and q22 
  cQ = diag(0,4); cQ[1,1]=cQ1; cQ[2,2]=cQ2 
  cR = para[4]
  kf = Kfilter0(num, jj, A, mu0, Sigma0, Phi, cQ, cR)
  return(kf$like) }

# Initial Parameters 
mu0 = c(.7,0,0,0); Sigma0 = diag(.04,4) 
init.par = c(1.03,.1,.1,.5) # Phi[1,1], the 2 cQs and cR 

# Estimation and Results 
est = optim(init.par, Linn,NULL, method='BFGS', hessian=TRUE, 
        control=list(trace=1,REPORT=1)) 
SE = sqrt(diag(solve(est$hessian))) 
u = cbind(estimate=est$par, SE) 
rownames(u)=c('Phi11','sigw1','sigw2','sigv'); u 

# Smooth 
Phi = diag(0,4); Phi[1,1] = est$par[1] 
Phi[2,]=c(0,-1,-1,-1); Phi[3,]=c(0,1,0,0); Phi[4,]=c(0,0,1,0) 
cQ1 = est$par[2]; cQ2 = est$par[3] 
cQ = diag(1,4); cQ[1,1]=cQ1; cQ[2,2]=cQ2 
cR = est$par[4] 
ks = Ksmooth0(num,jj,A,mu0,Sigma0,Phi,cQ,cR) 

# Plots 
Tsm = ts(ks$xs[1,,], start=1960, freq=4) 
Ssm = ts(ks$xs[2,,], start=1960, freq=4)
p1 = 3*sqrt(ks$Ps[1,1,]); p2 = 3*sqrt(ks$Ps[2,2,]) 
par(mfrow=c(2,1)) 
plot(Tsm, main='Trend Component', ylab='Trend') 
xx = c(time(jj), rev(time(jj))) 
yy = c(Tsm-p1, rev(Tsm+p1)) 
polygon(xx, yy, border=NA, col=gray(.5, alpha = .3)) 
plot(jj, main='Data & Trend+Season', ylab='J&J QE/Share', ylim=c(-.5,17)) 
xx = c(time(jj), rev(time(jj)) ) 
yy = c((Tsm+Ssm)-(p1+p2), rev((Tsm+Ssm)+(p1+p2)) ) 
polygon(xx, yy, border=NA, col=gray(.5, alpha = .3)) 

# Forecast 
n.ahead = 12 
y = ts(append(jj, rep(0,n.ahead)), start=1960, freq=4) rmspe = rep(0,n.ahead)
x00 = ks$xf[,,num]; P00 = ks$Pf[,,num] 
Q = t(cQ)%*%cQ
R = t(cR)%*%(cR) 
for (m in 1:n.ahead){ 
  xp = Phi%*%x00; Pp = Phi%*%P00%*%t(Phi)+Q 
  sig = A%*%Pp%*%t(A)+R; K = Pp%*%t(A)%*%(1/sig) 
  x00 = xp; P00 = Pp-K%*%A%*%Pp 
  y[num+m] = A%*%xp; rmspe[m] = sqrt(sig) }

plot(y, type='o', main='', ylab='J&J QE/Share', ylim=c(5,30), 
 xlim=c(1975,1984)) 
upp = ts(y[(num+1):(num+n.ahead)]+2*rmspe, start=1981, freq=4) 
low = ts(y[(num+1):(num+n.ahead)]-2*rmspe, start=1981, freq=4) 
xx = c(time(low), rev(time(upp))) 
yy = c(low, rev(upp)) 
polygon(xx, yy, border=8, col=gray(.5, alpha = .3)) abline(v=1981, lty=3)
```

Then there's error for est (Estimation and Results).

```
> est = optim(init.par, Linn,NULL, method='BFGS', hessian=TRUE, 
+             control=list(trace=1,REPORT=1)) 
Error in optim(init.par, Linn, NULL, method = "BFGS", hessian = TRUE,  : 
  initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite
```

This is my data  used for jj

```
jj<-c ( 102.95, 102.77, 103.06, 103.39, 102.98, 103.28, 102.64, 102.82, 102.14, 102.59, 103.12,
102.92, 103.65,     NA,     NA, 102.98, 102.86, 102.80, 102.30, 102.61, 102.83, 103.12,
102.78, 102.73, 102.46, 102.29, 102.73, 102.62, 102.56, 102.25, 102.22, 102.35, 102.45,
102.17, 102.05, 102.52, 101.87,     NA, 102.16, 102.11, 102.14, 101.61, 101.96, 101.91,
102.08, 102.35, 101.95, 101.99, 101.70, 102.00, 101.93, 101.98, 101.94, 101.96, 101.77,
102.09, 102.22, 101.70, 102.03, 102.11, 101.95, 102.31, 101.91, 101.79, 103.18, 101.88,
102.02,     NA,     NA, 101.72, 102.06, 101.98, 102.10)
```

Why the error caused and anyone can run this code with the data I provide? The book doesn't provide data jj.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the data `jj` is provided in the package `astsa`. If you have installed the package you can check it using `astsa::jj`. The class of `astsa::jj` is `ts` meaning that it is a time series object.

However, the error in your optimization is caused by the `NA`'s.

I've attached a `reprex` where you can see that the example of the book seems to work.

And in a second example I've transformed your data into a ts object after eliminating the `NA` values. Optimization with optim worked for the adjusted data, but the algorithm has not reached convergence and stopped after 100 iterations. The computation of the standard errors throws a warning that `NaNs` were produced. The reason for that is that the variance-covariance matrix has a negative value on the diagonal (but this are the variances and they should be strictly positive).

Since I don't know the example taken from the book, you'll try and find out better starting values for your data.

In the attached `reprex` the forecast plot is at the end of the document (no idea why it is not in the right place), but that's not important.

```r
library(astsa)
print(jj) #  dataset inside package astsa
#>           Qtr1      Qtr2      Qtr3      Qtr4
#> 1960  0.710000  0.630000  0.850000  0.440000
#> 1961  0.610000  0.690000  0.920000  0.550000
#> 1962  0.720000  0.770000  0.920000  0.600000
#> 1963  0.830000  0.800000  1.000000  0.770000
#> 1964  0.920000  1.000000  1.240000  1.000000
#> 1965  1.160000  1.300000  1.450000  1.250000
#> 1966  1.260000  1.380000  1.860000  1.560000
#> 1967  1.530000  1.590000  1.830000  1.860000
#> 1968  1.530000  2.070000  2.340000  2.250000
#> 1969  2.160000  2.430000  2.700000  2.250000
#> 1970  2.790000  3.420000  3.690000  3.600000
#> 1971  3.600000  4.320000  4.320000  4.050000
#> 1972  4.860000  5.040000  5.040000  4.410000
#> 1973  5.580000  5.850000  6.570000  5.310000
#> 1974  6.030000  6.390000  6.930000  5.850000
#> 1975  6.930000  7.740000  7.830000  6.120000
#> 1976  7.740000  8.910000  8.280000  6.840000
#> 1977  9.540000 10.260000  9.540000  8.729999
#> 1978 11.880000 12.060000 12.150000  8.910000
#> 1979 14.040000 12.960000 14.850000  9.990000
#> 1980 16.200000 14.670000 16.020000 11.610000

num = length(jj)
A = cbind(1,1,0,0) 
# Function to Calculate Likelihood 
Linn =function(para){ 
  Phi = diag(0,4)
  Phi[1,1] = para[1] 
  Phi[2,]=c(0,-1,-1,-1)
  Phi[3,]=c(0,1,0,0)
  Phi[4,]=c(0,0,1,0) 
  cQ1 = para[2]; cQ2 = para[3] # sqrt q11 and q22 
  cQ = diag(0,4); cQ[1,1]=cQ1; cQ[2,2]=cQ2 
  cR = para[4]
  kf = Kfilter0(num, jj, A, mu0, Sigma0, Phi, cQ, cR)
  return(kf$like) }

# Initial Parameters 
mu0 = c(.7,0,0,0); Sigma0 = diag(.04,4) 
init.par = c(1.03,.1,.1,.5) # Phi[1,1], the 2 cQs and cR 

# Estimation and Results 
est = optim(init.par, Linn,NULL, method='BFGS', hessian=TRUE, 
            control=list(trace=1, REPORT=1)) 
#> initial  value 2.693644 
#> iter   2 value -0.853526
#> iter   3 value -9.416505
#> iter   4 value -10.241752
#> iter   5 value -19.419809
#> iter   6 value -30.441188
#> iter   7 value -31.825543
#> iter   8 value -32.248413
#> iter   9 value -32.839918
#> iter  10 value -33.019870
#> iter  11 value -33.041749
#> iter  12 value -33.050583
#> iter  13 value -33.055492
#> iter  14 value -33.078152
#> iter  15 value -33.096870
#> iter  16 value -33.098405
#> iter  17 value -33.099018
#> iter  18 value -33.099385
#> iter  19 value -33.099498
#> iter  19 value -33.099498
#> final  value -33.099498 
#> converged
SE = sqrt(diag(solve(est$hessian))) 
u = cbind(estimate=est$par, SE) 
rownames(u)=c('Phi11','sigw1','sigw2','sigv'); u 
#>           estimate         SE
#> Phi11 1.0350847657 0.00253645
#> sigw1 0.1397255477 0.02155155
#> sigw2 0.2208782663 0.02376430
#> sigv  0.0004655672 0.24174702

# Smooth 
Phi = diag(0,4); Phi[1,1] = est$par[1] 
Phi[2,]=c(0,-1,-1,-1); Phi[3,]=c(0,1,0,0); Phi[4,]=c(0,0,1,0) 
cQ1 = est$par[2]; cQ2 = est$par[3] 
cQ = diag(1,4); cQ[1,1]=cQ1; cQ[2,2]=cQ2 
cR = est$par[4] 
ks = Ksmooth0(num,jj,A,mu0,Sigma0,Phi,cQ,cR) 

# Plots 
Tsm = ts(ks$xs[1,,], start=1960, freq=4) 
Ssm = ts(ks$xs[2,,], start=1960, freq=4)
p1 = 3*sqrt(ks$Ps[1,1,]); p2 = 3*sqrt(ks$Ps[2,2,]) 
par(mfrow=c(2,1)) 
plot(Tsm, main='Trend Component', ylab='Trend') 
xx = c(time(jj), rev(time(jj))) 
yy = c(Tsm-p1, rev(Tsm+p1)) 
polygon(xx, yy, border=NA, col=gray(.5, alpha = .3)) 
plot(jj, main='Data & Trend+Season', ylab='J&J QE/Share', ylim=c(-.5,17)) 
xx = c(time(jj), rev(time(jj)) ) 
yy = c((Tsm+Ssm)-(p1+p2), rev((Tsm+Ssm)+(p1+p2)) ) 
polygon(xx, yy, border=NA, col=gray(.5, alpha = .3))
```

[image]

```r
# Forecast 
n.ahead = 12 
y = ts(append(jj, rep(0,n.ahead)), start=1960, freq=4) 
rmspe = rep(0,n.ahead)
x00 = ks$xf[,,num]; P00 = ks$Pf[,,num] 
Q = t(cQ)%*%cQ
R = t(cR)%*%(cR) 
for (m in 1:n.ahead){ 
  xp = Phi%*%x00; Pp = Phi%*%P00%*%t(Phi)+Q 
  sig = A%*%Pp%*%t(A)+R; K = Pp%*%t(A)%*%(1/sig) 
  x00 = xp; P00 = Pp-K%*%A%*%Pp 
  y[num+m] = A%*%xp; rmspe[m] = sqrt(sig) }

plot(y, type='o', main='', ylab='J&J QE/Share', ylim=c(5,30), 
     xlim=c(1975,1984)) 
upp = ts(y[(num+1):(num+n.ahead)]+2*rmspe, start=1981, freq=4) 
low = ts(y[(num+1):(num+n.ahead)]-2*rmspe, start=1981, freq=4) 
xx = c(time(low), rev(time(upp))) 
yy = c(low, rev(upp)) 
polygon(xx, yy, border=8, col=gray(.5, alpha = .3)) 
abline(v=1981, lty=3)


# Example 2: New jj data: 
jj_new <- c( 102.95, 102.77, 103.06, 103.39, 102.98, 103.28, 102.64, 102.82, 102.14, 102.59, 103.12,
             102.92, 103.65,     NA,     NA, 102.98, 102.86, 102.80, 102.30, 102.61, 102.83, 103.12,
             102.78, 102.73, 102.46, 102.29, 102.73, 102.62, 102.56, 102.25, 102.22, 102.35, 102.45,
             102.17, 102.05, 102.52, 101.87,     NA, 102.16, 102.11, 102.14, 101.61, 101.96, 101.91,
             102.08, 102.35, 101.95, 101.99, 101.70, 102.00, 101.93, 101.98, 101.94, 101.96, 101.77,
             102.09, 102.22, 101.70, 102.03, 102.11, 101.95, 102.31, 101.91, 101.79, 103.18, 101.88,
             102.02,     NA,     NA, 101.72, 102.06, 101.98, 102.10)

jj <- ts(jj_new[!is.na(jj_new)])
num = length(jj)
A = cbind(1,1,0,0) 
# Estimation and Results 
est_new = optim(init.par, Linn,NULL, method='BFGS', hessian=TRUE, 
                control=list(trace=1, REPORT=1)) 
#> initial  value 69066.649055 
#> iter   2 value 13379.941416
#> iter   3 value 897.811170
#> iter   4 value 897.744837
#> iter   5 value 740.086083
#> iter   6 value 704.062900
#> iter   7 value 647.291087
#> iter   8 value 605.620617
#> iter   9 value 577.994261
#> iter  10 value 577.994023
#> iter  11 value 577.948157
#> iter  12 value 577.946077
#> iter  13 value 577.944346
#> iter  14 value 577.940792
#> iter  15 value 577.934726
#> iter  16 value 577.905521
#> iter  17 value 577.830290
#> iter  18 value 577.701675
#> iter  19 value 577.701480
#> iter  20 value 577.407053
#> iter  21 value 577.194089
#> iter  22 value 576.554158
#> iter  23 value 567.194439
#> iter  24 value 539.288477
#> iter  25 value 531.890806
#> iter  26 value 531.036336
#> iter  27 value 531.030643
#> iter  28 value 530.956134
#> iter  29 value 530.918352
#> iter  30 value 530.890127
#> iter  31 value 530.887646
#> iter  32 value 530.885713
#> iter  33 value 530.338301
#> iter  34 value 530.231457
#> iter  35 value 530.229078
#> iter  36 value 530.222573
#> iter  37 value 530.220160
#> iter  38 value 530.206317
#> iter  39 value 530.179131
#> iter  40 value 530.083081
#> iter  41 value 529.669557
#> iter  42 value 528.424740
#> iter  43 value 528.028025
#> iter  44 value 528.025772
#> iter  45 value 527.992265
#> iter  46 value 527.988454
#> iter  47 value 527.984442
#> iter  48 value 527.954276
#> iter  49 value 527.890590
#> iter  50 value 527.626120
#> iter  51 value 525.410701
#> iter  52 value 525.263544
#> iter  53 value 525.262081
#> iter  54 value 525.245961
#> iter  55 value 525.238839
#> iter  56 value 525.165379
#> iter  57 value 524.994817
#> iter  58 value 522.481418
#> iter  59 value 516.856037
#> iter  60 value 481.813924
#> iter  61 value 481.808421
#> iter  62 value 481.755703
#> iter  63 value 481.695417
#> iter  64 value 481.680106
#> iter  65 value 481.664492
#> iter  66 value 481.662879
#> iter  67 value 481.654499
#> iter  68 value 481.555816
#> iter  69 value 478.911532
#> iter  70 value 478.569138
#> iter  71 value 478.564163
#> iter  72 value 477.213754
#> iter  73 value 476.426603
#> iter  74 value 476.421185
#> iter  75 value 476.098605
#> iter  76 value 476.011245
#> iter  77 value 476.005941
#> iter  78 value 476.000627
#> iter  79 value 475.994552
#> iter  80 value 475.976022
#> iter  81 value 475.902453
#> iter  82 value 475.894178
#> iter  83 value 475.425270
#> iter  84 value 474.679311
#> iter  85 value 471.311778
#> iter  86 value 470.959303
#> iter  87 value 470.953483
#> iter  88 value 470.947660
#> iter  89 value 470.941837
#> iter  90 value 470.936012
#> iter  91 value 470.930187
#> iter  92 value 470.924361
#> iter  93 value 470.918534
#> iter  94 value 470.912707
#> iter  95 value 470.906878
#> iter  96 value 470.901049
#> iter  97 value 470.895219
#> iter  98 value 470.889388
#> iter  99 value 470.883557
#> iter 100 value 470.877724
#> final  value 470.877724 
#> stopped after 100 iterations

SE_new = sqrt(diag(solve(est_new$hessian))); SE_new
#> Warning in sqrt(diag(solve(est_new$hessian))): NaNs wurden erzeugt
#> [1]  25.22358 124.10763       NaN 103.69772
u_new = cbind(estimate=est_new$par, SE_new) 
rownames(u_new)=c('Phi11','sigw1','sigw2','sigv'); u_new
#>          estimate    SE_new
#> Phi11  -0.8707774  25.22358
#> sigw1  -5.8028386 124.10763
#> sigw2 776.3957560       NaN
#> sigv  371.0135779 103.69772
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>